# spring boot 1.5.1 and elasticsearch 5.4

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a spring boot 1.5.1 application and live Elasticsearch 5.4 which I can't downgrade to 2.4.5 or so
Spring data supports only 2.x.x versions of Elasticsearch
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/860 (formerly DATAES-285).

What is the best way to make spring boot work with remote elasticsearch together with out spring-data?

Comment: There is no way to use spring data with elasticsearch 5.X, use elastic search APIs instead of spring data.

Comment: @Jobin Yes, but where is a way to use spring with elasticsearch with out spring data
I want to know the best way of doing this. Like how to configure it, what classes should be spring's beans and so on

Comment: I would give [Spring RestTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) a try.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-elasticsearch-example/

but you need to wait when spring boot update module for elasticsearch